# Custom WPF image binding in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I have inherited a WPF project that generates XAML dynamically and binds Image objects to bitmaps also generated dynamically in code. Sample code below shows how this works:

```
public class XamlImageStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new <see cref="XamlImageStore"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    static XamlImageStore()
    {
        images = new Dictionary<string, BitmapSource>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Images used in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, BitmapSource> images;

    internal static void AddImage(string imageID, BitmapSource image)
    {
        images[imageID] = image;
    }

    public static string GetImageId(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ImageIdProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageId(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageIdProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageId", typeof(string), typeof(XamlImageStore), new UIPropertyMetadata("0", ImageIdChanged));

    private static void ImageIdChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image target = obj as Image;
        if (target != null)
        {
            string imageID = e.NewValue.ToString();
            if (images.ContainsKey(imageID))
            {
                // Set the image source.
                target.Source = images[imageID];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main application window (application namespace and output exe is `DynamicXamlImage`):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string customImageID = "ABCD";
    XamlImageStore.AddImage(customImageID, GetBitmap());

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlTextWriter xamlWriter =  new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

    xamlWriter.WriteStartElement("Canvas");
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06");
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:local", "clr-namespace:DynamicXamlImage;assembly=DynamicXamlImage");

    xamlWriter.WriteStartElement("Image");
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("local:XamlImageStore.ImageId", customImageID);
    xamlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xamlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xamlWriter.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(ms);
    appGrid.Children.Add(canvas);
}

private WriteableBitmap GetBitmap() 
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(20, 20, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);
    byte[] pixels = new byte[] { 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };
    wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 20, 20), pixels, 20, 0);

    return wb;
}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Can somebody explain how this binding works as I could not find anything on this method?

The reason I ask is that I have to extend the XAML generation code to support opacity masks that are generated dynamically and I have no idea how to make an `ImageBrush` load the mask in the same way.

Comment: there no bindings in the implementation above. just property (attribute) assignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can somebody explain how this binding works?

There is no data binding involved.

`XamlImageStore` consists of two parts:

- a Dictionary that maps ID strings to `BitmapSource` instances
- an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0) named `ImageId` with a PropertyChanged callback that assigns a BitmapSource from the Dictionary to the `Source` property of an Image element on which the attached property was set.

In the code sample a BitmapSource that is returned from the `GetBitmap()` method is added to the Dictionary with the key `"ABCD"`. Then the attached property is set on an Image element with value `"ABCD"`, which results in the Source of the Image set to the previously created BitmapSource.

---

As a note, the static constructor of the `XamlImageStore` class is redundant. You could as well write

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, BitmapSource> images
    = new Dictionary<string, BitmapSource>();
```

The PropertyChangedCallback could also be written a bit more efficient:

```
private static void ImageIdChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (obj is Image target)
    {
        string imageID = e.NewValue.ToString();

        if (images.TryGetValue(imageID, out BitmapSource bitmap))
        {
            target.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also be aware that the whole idea of having this helper class may be redundant. You could as well use XAML Resources, e.g. like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string customImageID = "ABCD";

    // *** see here ***
    Resources[customImageID] = GetBitmap();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlTextWriter xamlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

    xamlWriter.WriteStartElement("Canvas");
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06");
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:local", "clr-namespace:DynamicXamlImage;assembly=DynamicXamlImage");

    xamlWriter.WriteStartElement("Image");

    // *** and here ***
    xamlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Source", $"{{DynamicResource {customImageID}}}");
    xamlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xamlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xamlWriter.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(ms);
    appGrid.Children.Add(canvas);
}
```